# Sitecore 8.0 Rev 3 with WFFM 2.4 and Glass.Mapper 4.0.11.63

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper, web-forms-for-marketers

Environment:

- Sitecore 8.0 Rev 3
- WFFM 2.4
- Glass.Mapper 4.0.11.63

I am having an issue with the above configuration. When I submit a WFFM form the data that is being saved is coming across as "System.String[]" rather than the actual text value. I opened a Sitecore ticket and they found it was because of Glass Mapper. If I disable glass (Glass.Mapper.Sc.config and Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config) the forms submit the correct values.

As a side note, I did apply the Sitecore patch which address this issue for collection types but that has nothing to do with Glass. Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a known Sitecore bug, strange it's linked to Glass... https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/311218

Comment: That patch only addresses DropList and ListItems. Sitecore technical support was the one that figured out disabling the Glass configs fixed it.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the issue, and I've used Glass+WFFM on those versions before. Possibly an issue with the latest version of Glass... I would be tempted to log an issue on the project: https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues

Comment: If anyone is tracking this I added an issue https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Michael Edwards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148361/michael-edwards) assisted me with the solution.

His response can be read below:

> This was not a Glass issue but related to the WFFM model binder not
>   being registered with the default MVC dependency resolver due to a
>   conflict between the project IOC container and the one that WFFM tries
>   to use.

The fix was to register "DefaultFieldValueBinder" with my Container. Once I did that it started to work.